# Move plugin-settings to 'Settings'-menu in the admin

Tags: plugins, admin, admin-menu

I hate it, when plugins add their own settings like this: 
[image: WordPress admin 1]

It's cluttered and annoying. Can I somehow move them in under 'Settings':

[image: WordPress admin 2]

I imagined something like, checking if there is a plugin by the given name; and if there is, then remove it from the admin bar, like this (however, this doesn't work):

```
function custom_menu_page_removing() {
    // Neither of these two work (the first is the 
    // link, the second is the slug
    remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=themepacific_jp_gallery' );
    remove_menu_page( 'tiled-gallery-carousel-without-jetpack' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_menu_page_removing' );
```

I then imagined adding a link to generel settings like this:

```
function example_admin_menu() {
    global $submenu;
    $url = home_url() . '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_dashboard';
    $submenu['options-general.php'][] = array('Yoast', 'manage_options', $url);
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'example_admin_menu');
```

But my two problems are these:

- I can't find the correct `remove_menu_page( 'URL' );` to remove either Yoast or TP Tiled Gallery. How do I do that?
- If I remove the Yoast, - what will then happen to the sub-menu? How do I access that:

[image: Yoast sub menu]

Comment: Different plugins behave differently, so the answers could be endless. I would recommend a plugin like [Admin Menu Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) to handle everything.

Comment: Is it at least just possible to simple hide them then (and not care about the settings for the given plugin)? I'm trying to keep the plugins to a minimum...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be making life complicated. Here's the code you need;

```
function menu_shuffle() {
  remove_menu_page( 'plugin-page' );
  add_submenu_page('options-general.php','Page Title', 'Menu Label','manage_options', 'plugin-page' );
};

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'menu_shuffle' );
```

`plugin-page` can be found by mousing over the existing menu label and getting the part after the `?page=`in this case `?page=plugin-page`

The Wordpress function definition for `add_submenu_page()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/ includes a list of all the menu page slugs (and you need the '.php').

so in the example above for Yoast (bless its pointy little head and use Hide SEO Bloat)

```
function menu_shuffle() {
  remove_menu_page( 'wpseo_dashboard' );
  add_submenu_page('options-general.php','Yoast SE0', 'SEO','manage_options', 'wpseo_dashboard' );
};

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'menu_shuffle' );
```

Comment: +1000 Big thanks.

Comment: Worth noting there's no provision for a second level submenu in Wordpress so things like Yoast that have a submenu are difficult to elegantly manage within another submenu

Answer (score 0):

For Yoast, you can easily hide it, the settings are also in the WP topbar. :)

To hide it, use this code :

```
function mte_custom_menu_page_removing() { 
remove_menu_page( 'wpseo_dashboard' );              //Yoast
```

I am also interested to know how to move all other plugins in the settings submenu.

[-> Maybe an other solution here](https://codetheworld.info/2016/11/deplacer-le-menu-dune-extension-wordpress-dans-un-sous-menu/)